# Making my own "draggable" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

It seems that my attempt at trying to replicate Jquery UI's draggable function has proven the Quantum Mechanics principle of a div existing in two places at once.

When I hold my mouse down on the box div and move the mouse cursor, the box div starts flashing like crazy and a "clone" of the box div appears to the southeast of the original box div and it is also flashing.

Here's the jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Sxrq/)

Comment: I have fixed your jsfiddle, give it a go now:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Sxrq/2/

Comment: @sally: Are you sure you actually fixed it? I'm still getting the same flickering with your version. EDIT: Never mind, I was looking at the wrong link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have fixed your jsfiddle, give it a go now:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Sxrq/2/

The issues were:

```
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:80px;
```

if you want to use margins then you'll have to subtract it from offsets

```
boxOff = $('#box').offset();
mouseOffX = e.pageX - boxOff.left;
mouseOffY = e.pageY - boxOff.top;
```

You should get `mouseOffX` and `mouseOffY` when `mousedown` event was called, not every time with `mousemove`

EDIT:
this one is with fixed margin issues:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Sxrq/3/

Comment: I found that just using `$('#box').position()` took care of the margin issues for me.

Comment: Yeah, but as long as your `box` isn't child element otherwise it will give you `offsets` wrt to that parent element not to the window....

Comment: Ah, I think you have a point. I *think* I avoided that in my version, but didn't consider how it would translate to yours. Just another reminder of why I shouldn't answer SO questions around 4 in the morning.

Comment: to fix that `margin` issue I have updated jdfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Sxrq/3/

Comment: I suspect it's because of the `$('#box').offset()` (as compared to `$('#box').position()`). The former returns the position relative to the document while the latter returns the position relative to the element's parent.

Comment: true, `position:relative` could work here but it's just a bit risky I would say :) coz if you've got any `parent element` with same `position:relative` then it's gonna set the `position` of our object wrt to that parent and we don't want that to happen.

Comment: there seems to be a glitch sometimes when I try to drag the div, the cursor changes to the "no-drop" or "not-allowed" style and I am dragging a "imprint" of the original div. Then the box div starts "sticking" to mouse cursor and moves along with the cursor even though I'm not holding down the mouse button. I see this in Firefox.

Comment: just add `overflow:hidden;` to that box and if you've got text inside that box then you'll have to make the box `unselectable`

Comment: why does overflow:hidden fix the problem?

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` limits the overflow of content inside your element, that's why it fixes our problem.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you get flickering is that you're calculating the offset of the mouse within the box each time the mouse moves. If you just calculate `mouseOffX` and `mouseOffY` once in `onmousedown`, you won't have it flicker.

<strike>Here is a modified version. It still has some issues, but no flickering: http://jsfiddle.net/RzqQE/</strike>

I'm going to try to fix the weird offset thing in my version, but I can't give you any guarantees--I'm liable to fall asleep at any moment.

Edit: Ah, fixed it. Here's a version that works: http://jsfiddle.net/7QzZM/

Now to explain what I did:

We don't really care about the position of the mouse in the block. What we care about is how much to move the block each time the mouse moves. We can figure this out by getting the deltas of the mouse's position (`dx` and `dy` in my code). To get the block's new position, we just add the deltas to its old position.

The other difference was that I used `$('#box').position()` instead of `$('#box').offset()`; this returns the position relative to the box's parent rather than relative to the document.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one up at 4 AM. Both your answer and Sally's answer are pretty good, but Sally's solution involves less changes to my code. Guess I'll decide which one is the answer later.

Comment: Chances are Sally's code is also less ad-hoc and so probably requires less editing to be presentable.